# how to create list of specific property from queryset in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a `queryset` from models query. The model has a field called `elem_num`.

**How can I create list with all of the `elem_nums` from the `queryset`?**

#### Example:

If Object has the fields "Name" and "Age" and query is:

```
query = [Object1, Object2]
```

how can I build a list like this:

```
age_list = [22, 31]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from myapp.models import MyModel
MyModel.objects.values_list('age', flat=True).order_by('age')
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list